# Error incompatible shapes in function model.fit()

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am new in Keras. I want to try U-net. I used this tutorial from tensorflow: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/samples/outreach/blogs/segmentation_blogpost/image_segmentation.ipynb.
I used the code for U-net creation with my own dataset. They have got images 256x256x3 and I made my images with same shape.
Now, I got error:

```
 InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [1376256] vs. [458752]
     [[{{node training/Adam/gradients/loss/conv2d_23_loss/mul_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs}}] ]
```

It is in function model.fit(). I have got 130 training examples and batch size is 5 (I know, that those number are small...).
Please, Can anybody know, what can cause this error in function model.fit()?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO questions which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1376256 is exactly 3 x 458752. I suspect you are not correctly accounting for your channels somewhere. As this appears to be on your output layer, it may be that you're trying to predict 3 classes when there are only 1.

In future, or if this doesn't help, please provide more information including the code for your model and number of classes you're trying to predict, so people can better help.